# Create Transfer Order through Restlet in Suitescript 2.x

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

All,

From a third party application, I am triggering a restlet in 2.x. And that restlet invokes a Map/Reduce script to create Transfer Orders. This is not creating transfer orders and throwing "*An unexpected SuiteScript error has occurred*". It looks the error is occurred due to the role I used. I tried internally through AJAX requests and find the script is working and creates Transfer Order records. So I understand the issue is due to role which the restlet uses. Can anyone help me, which specific permission I needed to add to the roles to create transfer orders?

Thanks in advance!
Babin

Comment: If this is a role/permission issue then the error thrown would include a note about which permission is missing.  If this is actually role related then Are you using One World? Is the role you access the RESTlet with restricted by Segment (Location, Dept etc)?

Comment: No, we are not using one world and it looks there is no restriction added. Also in the error, there is no additional messages related to permission.